# Add scrollviewer to grid

Tags: c#, xaml

How do I add a scrollviewer correctly to this layout ?

I tried adding the vertical scrollviewer to my main grid but it did not work.

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,167,8,-588" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="169*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="287*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Search" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ImageSource="/Assets/Apps-Magnifier-Metro-icon.png"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Grid.Column="1" Title="How It Works"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Physiotherapists" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Articles Of Week" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,364,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Blog Of Week" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,364,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Pod Casts" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,549,0,-111" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Jobs" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,549,0,-111" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Courses" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
    <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="About Us"/>
    <telerikPrimitives:RadHubTile HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="153" Width="168" Background="#25A1DA" Title="Contact"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scrollviewer` can only contain 1 element. Knowing that you have to make the `grid` scrollable and not it's content

It'll look like this :

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        //Content here          
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The **Grid** needs to be scrolled. Not the controls inside it.